How to run a command that requires input/output location on all folders in a directory, while correspondingly naming the new output folders?
For context, I have some experience with Unix and basic commands, but I'm seriously struggling to conceptualize more complex manipulations of files. Essentially, I have this command I want to run from this program Dorado. Usually, I will use commandline to navigate to the Dorado folder, and then run this command:
./dorado basecaller -x cpu --kit-name SQK-RBK114-24 hac /media/lab/DATA/Avery/raw_pod5/T0_redo_pod5 >
/media/lab/DATA/Avery/dorado7_basecalling/T0_redo_d7.bam 

The raw_pod5 folder has folders containing .pod5 files and the basecaller command in dorado can run with a folder of .pod5 files as input. I can manually go in and run this command on each folder, but it would be much easier for me to just be able to run this "basecaller" command with each folder so I can just set it and forget it, since running basecaller takes a while (a few hours to a few days depending on the folder size). Implicit in the command is that I would also need to create/name the corresponding output folder in the dorado7_basecalling directory. For example, for the folder T1UV_pod5 I want the output of basecaller to go to a folder called .../dorado7_basecalling/T1UV_d7.bam, for T2UV_pod5 it should be .../dorado7_basecalling/T2UV_d7.bam, etc.
I feel like if I was working in python, this would be easy for me (though it's been a while), but I struggle a lot to think intuitively in Unix. I also suck at regular expressions in Unix specifically. Am I trying to do something too complicated or is there a simple way I'm missing? Thanks!

This is my solution.
#!/bin/bash

BASEDIR="/media/lab/DATA/Avery"
INDIR="$BASEDIR/raw_pod5"
OUTDIR="$BASEDIR/dorado7_basecalling"
DORADO="/path/to/dorado_command"
OPTIONS="basecaller -x cpu --kit-name SQK-RBK114-24 hac"

ALLDIR=( $(find $INDIR/* -maxdepth 0 -type d) ) #Array with all POD5 directory

for POD5 in "${ALLDIR[@]}"
do
        #EXAMPLE: Searches inside the string "/media/lab/DATA/Avery/raw_pod5/T0_redo_pod5" the directory prefix "T0_redo" and returns the new name "T0_redo_d7.bam"
        D7BAM="$(echo "$POD5" | sed -r "s@^$INDIR\/(.*)_pod5@\1_d7\.bam@")"
        $DORADO "$OPTIONS" "$POD5" > "$OUTDIR/$D7BAM"
done

